Ошибка при выполнении QT5 и crypto++(cryptopp)
Имеется QT 5.15.10 собрана с помощью mingw. Так же библиотека crypto++(cryptopp) 5.6.2.Собрана тем же. Сборка проходит замечательно, в проект подключается, а при выполнении выдает следующую ошибку.
In memory integrity check failed. This may be caused by debug breakpoints or DLL relocation.
Crypto++ DLL integrity check failed. Actual MAC is: 2C367E727BD094344250B21C65359721637E4CEF

CryptoPP::Exception caught: FileStore: error opening file for reading: TestData/usage.dat

В какую сторону копать никто не подскажет?
Собирал cryptopp со следующими флагами
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = cryptopp
INCLUDEPATH += .
CONFIG += dll
CONFIG -= qt


error opening file for reading: TestData/usage.dat

это уже последствия. Да спасибо не обратил внимания, но он там выдал ключи, как с командной строки бы запускал и всё. Буду копать дальше
